# Windows Form vs Console Application

Tags: .net, winforms, console-application

Any idea on how does Windows Form stay even after its execution unless we hit on the close [X] mark explicitly. This is not the case for Console Application?

I would like to know how this is managed by .NET internally?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get this difference I believe you should read something about `Windows Messages` (`Messages Queue`, `Message loop`, etc.). For example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). .Net doesn't bring anything new here, it's more about windows applications itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken: a Windows Forms program only stays during its execution and does not remain after it. It only stops executing after you exit the program, for example by clicking the close [X] button.

Do you mean to ask what the difference is between console and windows applications, and why they execute differently when started from the command line? This is controlled by a flag in the (PE) executable header, which is set by the /subsystem:console or /subsystem:windows option of the linker. It is a totally insane method in my opinion; Unix uses a much more logical method for this (the user can specify himself whether the shell waits for it or not).

This is the same for both .NET and native executables.

Comment: Please bear with me if I am wrong, but what I see is the Form is still present. For e.g. I create a windows forms application, and drag drop a button on to the form. On the click event of the button I write something. After it executes the form still remains. In case of a Console once the main function finishes the exe also ends.

Comment: Yes, because the main function is still running. It is not the same function as the function behind the button. The main function contains an event loop which processes the messages from both the form buttons and the close/minimize/etc. buttons, and which exits once it has seen a WM_QUIT message, for example when the close button is clicked. Follow the link in Snowbear's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well WinForms have more code than just what you type. They don't close write away because the code is in a loop where it constantly checks for events, and if the event Close is triggered then they will close.

Imagine that you code something like this in your Console Application:

```
while(true)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Enter a Number: ");
   int x;
   Console.Read(X);

   if(x==-1) break;
   Console.Write(x*x);

}
```

The loop would repeat forever until a -1 is entered, you could say that something similar goes on with winforms. Of course this is an oversimplification but imagine something like that.

If you'd like to learn more you should research about `Windows Messages (Messages Queue, Message loop` as Snowbeard said